# Custom MSBuild Task throws ObjectDisposedException when making a HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I am trying to write a custom msbuild task that checks a if a website is available. But when my task end it throws a ObjectDisposedException with the following stack trace.

```
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle.DangerousAddRef(Boolean& success)
   at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.SafeHandleAddRef(SafeHandle pHandle, Boolean& success)
   at Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.SetEvent(SafeWaitHandle handle)
   at System.Threading.EventWaitHandle.Set()
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ReceiveStandardErrorOrOutputData(DataReceivedEventArgs e, Queue dataQueue, ManualResetEvent dataAvailableSignal)
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolTask.ReceiveStandardOutputData(Object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.OutputReadNotifyUser(String data)
   at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.FlushMessageQueue()
   at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.GetLinesFromStringBuilder()
   at System.Diagnostics.AsyncStreamReader.ReadBuffer(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.AsyncResult.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.DoAsyncCall()
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.AgileAsyncWorkerItem.ThreadPoolCallBack(Object o)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()
```

I don't understand what is causing this behavior.

Here is the simplest code snippet that shows the problem.

```
public class CustomTask : Task {
    public override bool Execute() {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to my own question. As part of the build file I was starting a instance of JBoss via the standalone.bat, now that file would block but I needed the build to continue so I did the following.

```
<Exec Command="$(StartWithJavaHome)" 
      WorkingDirectory="$(JBossPath)" Timeout="2000" ContinueOnError="true"/>
```

Which worked in that it didn't block anymore. But what was happening was that the Exec command was getting disposed but the JBoss instance was still writing to the std out, thus causing the error I was seeing.